# Measure of angle given by the external angle bisectors

Tags: geometry

I have the following problem: In a triangle ABC, the measure of the angle formed by the external angle bisectors of B and C is equal to twice the measure of the angle A. Find out the value of angle A.

Can anyone suggest how to approach this example?

Comment: @FernadoGómez I assume you mean the [external angle bisectors](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExteriorAngleBisector.html)?

Comment: @TobyMak yes, external angle bisectors, sorry, had to translate it from Spanish. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Directly from the question, we know that:

$$\frac{180º - B}{2} = \frac{180º - C}{2} = 2A$$

and we also know that:

$$A+B+C = 180º$$

Comment: Meaning then that: 

$$
\frac{180-B}{2}=2A  
B=180-4A
$$

And: 
$$
\frac{180-C}{2}=2A  
C=180-4A
$$

Hence:
$$
A+180-4A+180-4A=180  \
A=\frac{180}{7} 
$$

Would that be the answer?

Comment: @FernandoGómez Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you loads.